# cannot scroll contents in mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added scrollviewer to my WPF application but when I resize I still cannot see the controls

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <GroupBox Header = "Add Member"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Height="500">
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content = "Female"   FontSize="16" FontWeight="Normal" TabIndex="4" Margin="651,335,0,105"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Please add this property in your ScrollViewer:  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code and it looks fine to me (after removing margin from the radio button): http://screencast.com/t/12wUxd2HFFAJ